# Consolidate several sets of contacts with Google contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, google-workspace, google-contacts, gmail-contacts

I have 2 groups of different contacts on 2 copies of Outlook. There's a lot of overlapping between my partner contacts and mine, and I'd like to have a single, centralized repository. I was thinking of using Google contacts for this.

Is there a way or tool to merge theses contacts, remove duplicates and resolve inconstancies without losing data?

What do small to medium size companies use for this?

Comment: Google Contacts all by itself does a pretty good job of managing duplicates without losing information.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to export your contacts from your two Outlook accounts and other Gmail account and import these contact files into your main Gmail account. This process will create lots of duplicates, but you can use Google's duplicate remover tool built inside Google Contacts to remove and merge many of the duplicates.

Another service [Scrubly Duplicate Contact Remover](http://www.scrubly.com) can clean up the remaining duplicates Google's tool misses. The service is not free, but does a great job. It also imports your friend's contact information from Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter.